# Calling a form with this name in a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms

Let's say I have a form with a `Treeview`, the user will chose a node then press a button. This will open a second form depending on the selected node.

This is a treeview exemple:

```
Fruits
|___Apple
|___Kiwi
Vegetables
|___Potato
Mushrooms
```

In my projet, I have a form for each child node of the treeview (in this exemple I have a 'Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Potato' and 'Mushrooms' forms)

Note that the node name is the same as the form name.

For now, I use a select case to show the correct form :

```
Select Case treeview.SelectedNode.Name

    Case "Apple"
        Dim Uf As New Apple 'Apple is the name of the form
        Uf.Show()
    Case "Kiwi"
        Dim Uf As New Kiwi
        Uf.Show()
    Case "Potato"
        Dim Uf As New Potato
        Uf.Show()
    Case "Mushrooms"
        Dim Uf As New Mushrooms
        Uf.Show()

End Select
```

This work as intended, but the issue is that my treeview is very big and I have to do hundreds of cases.

How can I manage to make a new form the selected node variable instead ? I have tried something like that :

```
Dim Uf As New treeview.SelectedNode.Name
Uf.Show()
```

But `treeview.SelectedNode.Name` is not seen as a form. Do I really have to make a big select case or there is a trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
    Private Sub StartMyForm(formName As String)
        TryCast(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(Application.ProductName & "." & formName), Form).Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've got `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` with you code, I'll investigate.

Comment: Do your forms have the same product name? Is all under the same application? 
Replace “Application.ProductName” with form which need to be started  ProductName

Comment: Yes ! that was that. As my project is a class library used in an addin for another software, `Application.ProductName` was equal to the soft name, not the project name. I change that and this is working like a charm ! Thanks

Comment: Exactly.  Thanks sir ;)